# Coin tossing game with one yes/no question.

Tags: probability, statistics

Let's assume we are playing a game. You have $100$ coins, you toss them and do not tell me the results. I can ask one yes/no question and after your answer I'll start guessing the coin results. For each correct result I'll get $1$ dollar and for each wrong guess I'll lose $1$ dollar. What is the best strategy for me to play the game? What is the average income of the strategy?

Edit: Here is a strategy with higher than $1$ dollar return. Ask whether number of heads are greater than or equal to tails. If the answer is yes guess all them to be heads otherwise guess all of them to be tails.

Comment: In the original question, you get $0$ for guessing wrong. The results there can be mapped to the question here by multiplying the profit per coin by $2$ and subtracting $1$; so the profit of $\$53.98$ for $100$ coins determined by Brian Scott translates to a profit of $\$7.96$ here.

Comment: But still I'm not sure why the strategy above is the best strategy. Is there a way to prove it?

Comment: I don't know. I closed this as a duplicate because you asked exactly the same question, what the best strategy is. If you want a proof, I'd suggest that you post a new question where you link to these two and ask for a proof. (I think this would be preferable to reopening this question and editing it to ask about a proof – you can get a clean focus on the proof without the existing answers here about other strategies.)

Answer (score 0):

Theoretically, the best way to get information is by splitting all possible sequences into two equal sized groups, so asking  "is the first flip heads?" yields the best chance. Asking if there are more heads than tails is not as helpful since it does not split the possibilities into two equal groups (one group contains the 50/50 split sequences).

This answer is still up for debate - see this link for some other possibilities.

https://www.glassdoor.com/Interview/Imagine-I-flip-100-coins-in-a-sequence-and-you-need-to-guess-the-sequence-You-are-allowed-to-ask-one-yes-no-question-Wha-QTN_1369290.htm, and you can find other takes and reasoning on this question there.

Comment: All the answers in the link given are incorrect! It is interesting that I was asked the same question during the interview with the same firm. I almost when through the similar ideas presented in the comments but they were wrong. All I got was that some how using CLT one should be able to find a strategy that gives a much higher return than 1 dollar.

Comment: @user127776:  I clicked through and found only two strategies:  either to ask about one specific flip or to ask for the majority.  Why do you say asking about a single flip is wrong?

Comment: @user127776 that's interesting. Perhaps I then recommend that you include this in the question next time for context/your attempts... I was just giving my perspective on this question - it certainly is a tricky one. You don't have to mark my answer as correct if you really don't want to, but this certainly not a straightforward question which is open to interpretation. By the way, what do you mean CLT?

Comment: @Ross Millikan Because asking about one flip gives the average return of 1 dollar for the game. The interviewer told me you can get much better returns.

Comment: Unless the interviewer is willing to tell what strategy s/he thinks is superior, I would be prone not to believe it.  Maybe that is the real point of the question-to see how you react to clearly wrong data.  You can certainly ask about more flips and (with small probability) win a lot, but I don't think you can do better on average than $+1$.

Comment: @global05 CLT stands for central limit theorem.

Comment: @Ross Millikan I don't think so. At the end it was clear I failed the interview, the interviewer was nice enough to confirm the fact you need to use CLT in some smart way. (We both knew I have failed so there was no reason to conceal it, that was my understanding of the situation!)

Comment: The reason to conceal it is to prevent you from posting it on glass door.  I'll be interested to see if anybody here has a better answer.

Comment: @RossMillikan: I closed this as a duplicate. Brian Scott's answer to the original question says that you're expected to make a profit of $\$7.96$ if you ask about the majority.

Answer (score 0):

Another strategy is to ask if the first two flips are both heads.  If the answer is yes, which happens with probability $\frac 14$, you have an expectation of $+2$.  If the answer is no, which happens with probability $\frac 34$, you guess tails for both of the first two flips.  With probability $\frac 13$ after the answer you are $+2$ and with probability $\frac 23$ you are even.  In total you are $+1$ on average.  No better than asking about a single flip, but no worse, either.  This shows that dividing the possibilities evenly is not necessarily better than other choices.

Comment: If the answer is no, how do you know if it is not Head then Tail, or vice versa? Or are you just guessing?

Comment: @global05:  I am just guessing.  I said the chance I was right was $\frac 13$.  I then computed the average win of my strategy and got $+1$.  I get a better average result by guessing TT than by guessing TH or HT because if I am wrong I still break even.